# Azure Data Explorer ODBC External Tables - Tableau

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, tableau-desktop, external-tables

Does ODBC Tableau for Azure Data Explorer have support to connect to external tables.  I have these 3 tables I am able to query:
[image]

But in Tableau, I am unable to search and see the tables:

[image]

Comment: search with schema name eg dbo.test

Comment: @MKD - I will keep trying to search with schema name but unable to find still.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it seems the ADX external tables are indeed not listed, they can be referenced by a New Custom SQL.
Below is a demonstration on the publicly available cluster, `Help`.

Although in KQL external tables are referenced with a special syntax, e.g.:

```
external_table('TaxiRides')
| take 10
```

When using the SQL syntax, you refer to it as a regular table, e.g.:

```
select top 10 * from TaxiRides
```

[image: New Custom SQL]